# Помогите, пожалуйста, соседке из Польши! :)

Tags: пунктуация, орфография, грамотная-речь

Помогите, пожалуйста! Мне надо было написать сочинение по теме «Кинокартина „Ученик“ — социальная или экзистенциальная драма?»

Могли бы вы мне сказать, где я сделала ошибку? Я ещё не так хорошо знаю русский язык, но стараюсь. :)

Я буду очень очень благодарна!
Большое спасибо!

> Кинокартина Ученик указывает проблемы молодого человека на фоне разных вопросов, касающихся взросления, общества и религии. 
>   Заглавный герой - Вениамин это ученик лицея, только что входящий в мир взрослого человека и познающий правила, которые им управляют. Он, как каждый любoй молодой человек, руководствуется принципами, которые принял в последствие своих убеждений и опыта. Для него самым важным в жизни является религия и все аспекты его жизни подчинены религии.
>
> На своей дороге парень сталкивается с героями, которые сыграют важную роль в жизни молодого человека. Появляется мать и друзья, которые не понимают поведения мальчика и считают его странником. Ест даже школа, учителя и наука, которая по своей сути противостоят религии. Здесь возникает вечная тема, волнующая людей, что важнее: вера или просвещение и разум. Наиболее ярким представителем этой группы является учительница, которая олицетворяет собой разум и стремление человека все постичь умом. Венедикт часто вступает с нее в конфликты, смело указывая свой протест и мнение по тему возбуждённых вопросов: создания мира и человека, а даже контрацепции.
>
> Венедикт своим поведением создает себя в виде юродивого - чудака, отказываемого от выгод и наслаждений, верующего, который всё отдал Богу, а в конце человека который хочет изменять митр и чудотворца. 
>   В драме затрагивается даже вопрос веры абсолютной. Много случаи, представленных в фильме, намекают зрителям думать, что глубокая вера мальчика постепенно преображается в религиозный фанатизм. Венедикт проявляется агрессивное поведение и в конце концов приводит к смерти своего друга. Для него цель оправдывает средства и он ни перед чем не остановится. И здесь появляется вопрос ли оправдывает поведение своей веры все.
>
> Соединяя проблемы подростка, ищущего своей пути со сложными вопросами современного общества, кинокартина оказывается драмой оба социальной и экзистенциальной. Фильм призывает зрителя до обдуманная и отражения на затронутых вопросах. Трудно найти четкий, хороший ответ, но стоит задуматься об своему отношению к затронутым изданиям. Разнообразие персонажей, показанных в драме, и количество переплетенных нити, заставляет, что фильм долго останется в памяти зрителя.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом).

Comment: @Aer не гоните лошадей. Тут до исчерпывающего - как до Луны раком. РКИ- не математика и не программирование, число итераций - бесконечно. )))

Comment: @Марта, Надеюсь, здесь Вы скорее увидите. Я нашел фильм. Оказывается, он российский. kinopoisk.ru/film/922150 Герой - Вениамин, кто такой Венедикт?

Comment: @Марта Я добавил пропущенную мной правку ("по теме возбужденных" на "на тему поднятых" и "с нее" на "с ней") и еще по мелочи, остальное не считаю достаточно актуальным

Answer (score 2):

Еще несколько замечаний.

(1) "Даже" нужно почти везде заменить на "**также**"

(2) "*Заглавный герой*". Спорно. Бесспорно правильный вариант: **главный** герой.

(3) О фразе *"На своей дороге парень сталкивается с героями, которые сыграют важную роль в жизни молодого человека"*.

"На своей дороге" - стилистически не очень хорошо. Можно выбросить совсем. Можно заменить на "на своем жизненном пути".

"Парень" - заниженный стиль

"Парень" + "молодой человек" - перебор.

"Сыграют" - воспринимается как будущее время по отношению ко времени написания сочинения. Все, что происходит в рамках фильма, лучше описывать используя глаголы в настоящем времени. Если эти герои тут же после встречи начинают "играть важную роль", то просто "играют", если через некоторое врема - то "затем играют".

Мой вариант:

**На своем жизненном пути молодой человек сталкивается с героями, которые (затем) играют важную роль в его жизни.**

(4) О фразе "*Появляется мать и друзья, не понимающие поведения мальчика и считающие его странным.*"

Эту фразу я понимаю так. Матери не было в его жизни, друзей не было, они все "появляются" по ходу фильма. Друзья не понимают поведения мальчика. О том, понимает ли мать поведение мальчика, ничего не говорится.

Если Вы имели в виду другой смысл, фразу нужно переделать. Например, фразу   "**Появляются** *мать и друзья, не понимающие поведения мальчика и считающие его странным.*" можно понимать так, что и мать, и друзья не понимают поведения мальчика.

(5) "*Есть даже школа*". Правильно: есть **также** школа

(6) "которая противостоят" - нет огласования по числу

(7) "*Наиболее ярким представителем этой группы."* 
Какой такой "этой"?

(8) "*вступает с нее в конфликты*" Правильно: вступает с **ней** в конфликты

(9) "*указывая свой протест*" Правильно: **выражая** свой протест

(10) "*мнение по тему*" Правильно: мнение по **теме**

(11) "*Много случаев, представленных в фильме, предлагают зрителям думать*" Правильно: **заставляют** зрителей думать

(12) "*а даже контрацепции*" Правильно: а **также** контрацепции

(13) "*В драме затрагивается даже вопрос веры абсолютной*." Вы хотели сказать: "**также** вопрос веры абсолютной"?

(14) "*считают его странником*". Правильно (здесь): считают его **странным**

Comment: (1) - не обязательно. (2) - нет (3) - "парень" - да (я бы заменил на ("юноша"), остальное - нет. (4) нет, это же фильм. В любом случае надо уточнить у автора, прежде чем делать такой вывод (5) - да, хотя и со стопроцентной уверенностью. (6) - да (7)  - нет, читайте контекст (8) да (9) пожалуй да, хоте не совсем уверен (10) да (я пропустил, хотя видел) (11) да (12) да (13) Почему? Думаю, нет. ======== А остальное-то?

Comment: Главный vs. заглавный. Главный герой - бесспорно правильно, а заглавный - очень спорно. Ведь фильм назван "Ученик", а не "Бенедикт". БАС: ЗАГЛАВНЫЙ, -ая, -ое. Содержащий заглавие. З. лист. З-ая страница. З-ая роль (роль действующего лица, **именем** которого названа пьеса, фильм). З-ая буква (большая или прописная буква).

Comment: @Morkovkin По (3) и (4) Ваше "нет" не аргументировано, требуется  развернутое  обсуждение (не в рамках комментариев)

Comment: *Главный герой - бесспорно правильно, а заглавный - очень спорно* - Именно ученик. По главному герою. Обломов - тоже не имя. Будете спорить, что он - заглавный? Я бы согласился, что "заглавный" здесь ***стилистически***  не самое удачное на русский слух, но никак не семантически. А стилистика - дело автора, тем более иностранного - студента. Я думаю, что автору как раз и важно подчеркнуть, что "ученик" в заглавии - это и есть тот Бенедикт (или как он там), о котором она рассказывает.

Comment: *По (3) и (4) Ваше "нет" не аргументировано* -- Это как раз Ваше **"Сыграют" - воспринимается как будущее время по отношению ко времени написания сочинения* - совершенно "не аргументировано". Я так не считаю, вот и вся аргументация.  Аналогично и по поводу *Эту фразу я понимаю так*  - а я не так понимаю. А так, как написано у автора. По отношению к времени относительному. Как и положено в пересказе. У автора герой действует в настоящем времени. И потом еще такая вещь. Носители польского обычно в русских грамматических временах не путаются.

Comment: @Morkovkin Утверждение "Понимаю так, как написано" - основано на неверной посылке об осутствии вариантов в понимании текста вообще и обсуждаемого в частности. Вариантов, объективно существующих, и ошибочных.

Comment: *основано на неверной посылке об осутствии* - оно основано на верной посылке, что надо св уважением относится к сказанному автором, а не навязывать ему свое понимание. Вы и её, простите, переврали, и меня - и все на основании своей ложной посылки навязывать свой мнение о том, что хотел сказать автор. Я же исхожу из ***написанного***, а не из домыслов.

Comment: Ну, на таком уровне нет смысла продолжать диалог.

Comment: На таком уровне Вам не стоило его начинать. ))) Я вам высказал замечания, не нравится - не принимайте. Но сначала требовать от меня аргументов (которые по контексту абсолютно не нужны), а потом на основании голословного утверждения их же и отметать - это да, лучше не продолжайте.

Comment: @Morkovkin, Вы хотели сменить ник? Возьмите "Кактус" - Вам подойдет :)

Comment: @Morkovkin,  мой совет модератору в отношении Вас: "Казнить нельзя помиловать" Пусть понимает исходя из *написанного*  :)

Comment: если угроза применения админ ресурса - это последний аргумент, то считаю дискуссию законченной.

Comment: @Morkovkin, Это шутка была, поставьте запятую после "нельзя"

Answer (score 1):

Я попробую, но ограничусь минимальной правкой. Иначе это не ваше сочинение будет.

Сразу о кавычках в подобных конструкциях.
**«Кинокартина „Ученик“ — социальная или экзистенциальная драма?»** 
Это абсолютно нормативный вариант - два типа кавычек именно в таком порядке: "ёлочки" снаружи, "лапочки" внутри - для изданий бумажных считается главным. Обратите внимание на направление "лапочек".

Есть другой, альтернативный, если ёлочки почему-то невозможны, или для третьего уровня. Внешние кавычки - лапочки, внутренние одиночные. Но тоже с обязательным направлением. 
И наконец для текстов, не предназначенных для печати (как вот этот текст), можно заменить оба типа кавычек на *"прямые лапочки"*. Что я и сделал.
Все остальные варианты в русском тексте считаются неправильными.

Теперь текст. Рекомендуемые изменения - курсивом.

. . .

Кинокартина *"Ученик"* указывает *на* проблемы молодого человека на фоне вопросов взросления, общества и религии. Заглавный герой - *Вениамин, ученик* лицея, только *входящий в мир взрослых и познающий правила,* которые им управляют. Он, как *каждый молодой* человек, *руководствуется принципами, воспринятыми им через убеждения и опыт.* Для него самым важным в жизни является *религия, и* все аспекты его жизни подчинены религии.

На своей дороге *юноша* сталкивается с героями, которые сыграют важную роль в жизни молодого человека. Появляется мать и друзья, *не понимающие поведения мальчика и считающие его странным*. Есть даже школа, учителя и наука, которая по своей сути противостоят религии. *Здесь возникает вечная волнующая* людей тема, что важнее: вера или просвещение и разум. Наиболее ярким представителем этой группы является учительница, которая олицетворяет собой разум и стремление человека все постичь умом. Венедикт часто вступает с ней в конфликты, смело указывая свой протест и мнение *на тему поднятых* вопросов: создания мира и человека и даже контрацепции.

Венедикт своим поведением *показывает себя юродивым - чудаком, отказывающегося* от выгод и наслаждений, *верующего, отдавшего всё Богу*, а *в конце -- человека, который* хочет изменять митр(?) и чудотворца(?). В драме затрагивается даже вопрос веры абсолютной. Много случаев, представленных в фильме, *предлагают* зрителям думать, что глубокая вера мальчика постепенно преображается в религиозный фанатизм. Венедикт *проявляет* агрессивное поведение и в конце концов *доводит до* смерти своего друга. Для него цель оправдывает *средства, и* он ни перед чем не остановится. И здесь появляется *вопрос, оправдывает ли* всё *следование своей вере.*

Соединяя проблемы подростка, ищущего *свой путь,* со сложными вопросами современного общества, кинокартина оказывается *драмой социальной* и экзистенциальной. Фильм призывает зрителя *к осмыслению и восприятию*  затронутых *вопросов*. Трудно найти четкий, хороший ответ, но стоит задуматься *о своём отношении* к затронутым *проблемам*. Разнообразие персонажей, показанных в драме, и количество переплетенных *нитей*, *заставляет предположить*, что фильм *надолго* останется в памяти зрителя.

. . .

Марта, я исправил все неправильно употребленные слова и падежи, которые понял. Если смысл фразы непонятен - пометил вопросами. Если растолкуете (хотя бы по-польски), что имелось в виду, поправлю и их. Еще. Поменьше используйте слово "который", даже в деловой и научной речи в таких количествах в нем нет необходимости. Отступы в начале абзацев нужны, но тут они не передаются. Остальное пока не буду объяснять, это уже более продвинутый уровень.

Да, вот ещё. Если имя польское, то его не стоит переводить. Оставьте **Бенедикт**. К тому же "Венедикт" и "Вениамин" - это разные имена, не надо их смешивать.

Comment: большое спасибо! :)

Comment: "на проблемы на фоне"? "Заглавный герой - Вениамин" - главный герой, имени Вениамин нет в названии. "На своей дороге юноша сталкивается" - убрать начало, начать с юноши.

Comment: "Венедикт часто вступает с нее в конфликты, смело указывая свой протест и мнение по тему" - требуется корректура, перечитайте!

Comment: @GalinaAvanesova За ошибку - спасибо, но пожалуйста, без фамильярностей, сюда иностранцы ходят.

Comment: Морковушкин, я могу вообще не возникать. Легко!

Comment: @GalinaAvanesova  я вам модератора процитирую. пожалуйста, используйте обращения (чтобы ваш адресат получал уведомления). Для этого нужно набрать @+первые несколько букв никнейма. (С) Aer

Answer (score 1):

**В качестве варианта:
Кинокартина «Ученик» — социальная или философская драма?**

Кинокартина «Ученик» раскрывает проблемы молодого человека на фоне разных вопросов, касающихся тем взросления, общества и религии. Главный герой Вениамин — это ученик лицея, только  входящий в мир взрослых людей и познающий правила, которые им управляют. Он, как и любой молодой человек, руководствуется принципами и убеждениями, полученными опытным путем. Для него самым важным является религия, и все аспекты его жизни подчинены религии.

На своем пути  парень сталкивается с героями, которые играют важную роль в его жизни. Это его  мать и друзья, которые не понимают поведения мальчика и считают его странным. Это школа, учителя,  а также наука, которая по своей сути противостоит религии. Здесь возникает вечная тема, волнующая людей: что важнее — вера или просвещение и разум. Наиболее ярким представителем этой группы является учительница, которая олицетворяет собой разум и стремление человека все постичь умом. Венедикт часто вступает с ней в конфликты, смело высказывая своё протестное  мнение по самым разнообразным вопросам — о создании мира и человека и  даже о контрацепции.

Венедикт своим поведением делает из себя юродивого: чудака, отказывающегося от выгод и наслаждений, верующего, который всё отдал Богу, а потом чудотворца, который хочет изменить мир. В драме затрагивается даже вопрос абсолютной веры. Многие факты, представленные в фильме, намекают зрителям на то, что глубокая вера мальчика постепенно преображается в религиозный фанатизм. Венедикт проявляет агрессивное поведение и в конце концов приводит к смерти своего друга. Для него цель оправдывает средства,   он ни перед чем не остановится. И тогда ставится вопрос: может ли вера оправдать всё?

Соединяя проблемы подростка, ищущего свой путь,  со сложными вопросами современного общества, кинокартина оказывается драмой и социальной, и философской. Фильм призывает зрителя к размышлению над  затронутыми темами. Трудно найти четкий, хороший ответ, но стоит задуматься о своем отношении к показанным проблемам.

В целом это  интересный и значительный фильм. Разнообразие персонажей, изображенных в драме, а также  большое количество сюжетных линий склоняет к мнению, что картина надолго останется в памяти зрителя.

Comment: Не к чему придраться :) ....кроме того, что изменения довольно значительные.

Comment: Я старалась по возможности сохранить авторский текст,  но далеко не всегда получалось. Надеюсь, что мой вариант просто дополнит ответы других участников, которые уже  представили детальную разборку сочинения.

Comment: Тем не менее - это медвежья услуга. Видно, что писал не польский студент. Хотя придраться-то как раз можно... Начнем с того, что  "парень" - здесь совсем не по тексту. Во-вторых, домысливание едва ли не с первой фразы... Но это - в общем-то наплевать, главное, я сказал, несоответствие уровня текста реальным возможностям студента.

Comment: @Morkovkin Это учёба,  а она полезна в любом виде. Мой вариант называется "А я бы так написала". Для Вас, может быть,   главное - это оценку получить, а другие хотят научиться. И домысливание бывает полезным, оно показывает, как читающий воспринимает (понимает) написанное вами.  И еще раз повторяю - это школа, это нормально, это разные аспекты обучения. Ненормально, когда  между участниками форума нет диалога, дружбы и взаимопонимания.

Comment: @Sibylla пожалуйста, используйте обращения (чтобы ваш адресат получал уведомления). Для этого нужно набрать @+никнейм (плюс не нужен).

Comment: @Aer по первым буквам система только варианты предлагает - и не всегда корректно, кстати. Для получения оповещения ник в **самом комментарии** должен быть правильно написан (исключение - пробелы). Если там будет @+morkovki, @+morkovkin1 или "морковушкин" я его не получу (если раньше в теме не отмечался). Кстати, ник тут можно сменить? Мой известный "однофамилец" умер и мне стало не очень уютно под эти псевдонимом.

Comment: @Morkovkin перейдем в чат: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54586/morkovkin.

Answer (score 0):

1. "Кинокартина Ученик указывает..."

Напрашивается либо точка после слова "Кинокартина", либо кавычки, заключающие слово "ученик".

2. "Заглавный герой..."

Я начал бы фразу так: "Главный герой, Вениамин - это ученик лицея..."

3. "...которые принял в последствие своих убеждений и опыта..."

Мой вариант: "которые принял как вывод из своих убеждений и опыта..."

4. Непонятно звучит фраза, что на жизненом пути молодого человека "появляется мать".

Очевидно (во всех смыслах), что мать появилась намного раньше.

5. Почему "странником"?  Мать и друзья решили, что парень слишком много путешествует?  Может быть, под "странником" Вы подразумеваете странного человека?
6. "Ест даже школа, учителя и наука..."  Может быть, не "ест", а "есть"?  В таком случае фразу можно было бы сконструировать (в данном контексте) так: "Кроме того, парень находится в атеистическом окружении - школа, наука, педагоги".  (Множественное от "учитель" дискутируется филологами - возможен вариант "учители".  Лично я жду, чем кончится спор, и пишу "педагоги").
7. В той же фразе: "которая" (единственное число) - "противостоят" (множественное).  Исправлено в предыдущем пункте.
8. "Венедикт часто вступает с нее в конфликты..."  Вениамин или все же Венедикт?  И "с нее" или "с ней" (с нею)?
9. "...смело указывая свой протест и мнение по тему возбуждённых вопросов:"  Мой вариант: "...смело выражая свой протест и высказывая мнение по теме поднятых вопросов".
10. "...отказываемого от выгод и наслаждений..." - пассивный оборот, тогда как здесь требуется активный: "отказывающего себе в выгодах и наслаждениях".
11. "а в конце человека который хочет" - пропущена запятая в начале вводного предложения.
12. "...который хочет изменять митр и чудотворца" - совершенно непонятен смысл фразы.  (Изменить чудотворца - это лихо!)
13. "Много случаи, представленных в фильме, намекают зрителям думать..." - мысль выражена совершенно не по-русски.  Наверно, имелось в виду: "Много эпизодов, показанных в фильме, заставляют зрителей думать..."
14. "Венедикт проявляется агрессивное поведение и в конце концов приводит к смерти своего друга".  Тоже убийственно нерусская фраза.  Вариант: "Поведение Венедикта (Вениамина) становится агрессивным, что в конце концов приводит к смерти друга главного героя".
15. "И здесь появляется вопрос ли оправдывает поведение своей веры все."  (отсутствие знака препинания после слова "вопрос", нарушение позиции частицы "ли", затуманенный смысл).  Я бы написал (если правильно понял смысл предложения): "И здесь возникает вопрос: оправдывает ли фанатичная вера все действия и поступки человека".

"Соединяя проблемы подростка, ищущего своей пути со сложными вопросами современного общества, кинокартина оказывается драмой оба социальной и экзистенциальной. Фильм призывает зрителя до обдуманная и отражения на затронутых вопросах. Трудно найти четкий, хороший ответ, но стоит задуматься об своему отношению к затронутым изданиям. Разнообразие персонажей, показанных в драме, и количество переплетенных нити, заставляет, что фильм долго останется в памяти зрителя."

16. Не останавливаясь на деталях (просто устал уже), просто покажу, как бы я написал этот

абзац:

"Соединяя проблемы подростка, идущего своим путем, со сложными вопросами современного общества, кинокартина оказывается драмой как социальной, так и экзистенциальной. Фильм призывает зрителя обдумать и проанализировать затронутые вопросы. Трудно найти четкий, исчерпывающий ответ на эти вопросы, но стоит задуматься о своем отношении к затронутой теме. Глубина и сложность сюжета заставят зрителя долго помнить поднятую тему."

---

Если Вы иностранка (т.е. русский язык не является Вашим родным), то написанный Вами текст в общем очень неплох и понятен на 95%.  Но вот Вам маяк для ориентировки: Дитмар Эльяшевич Розенталь, филолог, профессор Московского 
 университета.  Родился в Польше, в семейных разговорах использовал польский и идиш, еще в юности изучил несколько иностранных языков, в частности - русский.  Судьба забросила его в Россию, где он стал блестящим и непревзойденным знатоком русского языка, чувствующим его тончайшие нюансы.

Поищите в интернете: Дитмар Эльяшевич Розенталь.  Ориентируйтесь на него!

Второй пример иностранца, в совершенстве овладевшего русским языком: датчанин Владимир Даль, создавший совершенно потрясающий, уникальный "Толковый словарь живого великорусского языка".

Успехов Вам!

Comment: В целом поддерживаю, но:(1) "принял как вывод из своих убеждений и опыта" - плохо (я бы предложил "исходя из своих убеждений"); (2) "обдумать и проанализировать" - тавтология

Comment: @ЛеонидКозлов Второе "наше все" ДЭР никогда не занимался преподаванием РКИ. И не имел публикаций подобного рода. Что может у него взять польский студент данного уровня? Кроме трех-четырех правил пунктуации - если вообще их поймет. Учебники же стилистики - это вообще для профессионалов.